# I need a recommendation for software to control an HOA site

Tags: cms

I've got a friend who is the head of his Home Owner's Association.  He wants me to help him move to an easier to update.

I'm thinking of using a hosted CMS solution from GoDaddy, namely Jooma.  But I thought I'd ask here if anyone had any easier ideas.

Key points:

1. Ability to create pages at will and include them in navigation
2. Be able to email to a group a link or embedded content (monthly newsletters)
3. Have a "secure" area that is only accessible with a username/password area.

I don't know if Joomla will satisfy all of those requirements, but I think it gets me close and is free (well, included with paid hosting at GoDaddy).

Can anyone else speak up to any kind of success/failure you have had with Joomla, Drupal, DotNetNuke, etc?

Comment: Sounds like it should end up on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **Migrated**:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/i-need-a-recommendation-for-software-to-control-an-hoa-site